# How to align Two image view in same bottm line in android?

Tags: android, imageview

I have two imageView with two different size image. anyone one have idea how to align two image from baseline?

Comment: What's you effort , you should share your layout code to get assistance or help.

Comment: Give some more details to solve your problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put these images in a `RelativeLayout`, one has `@+id/first`, another `@+id/second`,
then in the second image specify: `android:alignBottom="@id/first"`

Comment: absolutely what i am looking for. Thanks. had never use alignBOttom.and android:baseLine do the same work :)

Answer (score 0):

Wrap them in a linearlayout with equal weighting.